# Accessing and adding data from different constructors

Tags: java

I have classes named `Item`, `Store`, `Customer`.

I am using `LinkedList` to move around classes. I have no experience using LinkedList. Just starting a couple days ago.

Item class

```
public class Item{
   public Item(Store store, String code, String name){
      this.code = code;
      this.name = name;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString(){
      return name + " : " + code ;
}
```

Store class

```
public class Store{
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    public Store(String name, String number){
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
   public void addItem(String code, String name){
      items.add(new Item(code, name);
   }
   public void viewItem(){
     for(Item item: items) 
       System.out.println(item);
   }
}
```

I am not quite sure about this part when I am only allowed to add the item to the store.
Then I will add the store to the customer.
So, customer can choose from the store.

```
Customer

    public class Customer{
        private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();
        public Customer(){
            stores.add(new Store("Game" , "1"));
            stores.add(new Store("Grocery" , "2"));
            // I struggle to add item with addItem method
            stores.get(0).addItem("001A" , "GTA");
            //I don't think it's actually way of adding
           //Anyway I think get(0). will add item to '0' index.So I would be the 'Game' store.
           stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
           stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

           stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
           stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
           stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
          new Customer().viewItem();
        }
        private void viewItem(){
           for(Store store: stores)
               store.viewItem();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to add item to Customer class only using LinkedList from Store class. I try this method.

But when I try this under store class to see if there are any data,

```
for(Item item: items)
    System.out.println(item)
```

I though the output would be like this

```
   GTA : 001A
   GOD OF WARS : 001B
   THE LAST OF US: 001C

   Sandwich: 002A
   Cup Noodle: 002B
   Ice Cream: 002C
```

But instead it print out NOTHING.

Can someone explain to me? I think I am wrong with addding or accessing data.

Also, for testing purposes. Can you tell me how can I check?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you put that loop in an actual method? Because your example doesn't show it like that.

Comment: What does your `main` method look like? Remember it's the `main` method that runs.

Comment: just added can you please explain to me what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `toString` in `Store` and `Customer` accordingly e.g. as given below:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Item {
    private String code, name;

    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + code;
    }
}

class Store {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    private String name, number;

    public Store(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void addItem(String code, String name) {
        items.add(new Item(code, name));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Item item : items) {
            sb.append(item.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Store store : stores) {
            sb.append("Store: ").append(store.getName()).append(System.lineSeparator()).append(store.toString())
                    .append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        System.out.println(customer);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Store: Game
GTA : 001A
GOD OF WARS : 001B
THE LAST OF US : 001C

Store: Grocery
Sandwich : 002A
Cup Noodle : 002B
Ice Cream : 002C
```

Comment: Thank you. Arvind. That's help a lot.

Comment: @ratRedTears - I've updated the answer to meet this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: but When I try to access it under 'Store' class. Nothing appears. How can I make it appear.

Comment: Just added the question @Arvind Can you pleases check out?